# Nginx subdomain - Home Assistant

Tags: nginx, proxy, home-assistant

I have a Home Assistant instance running on the same server like my nginx proxy, now I would like to create a subdomain under my public domain. In order to make my Home Assistant instance under the following url available https://something.com/homeassistant. I'm currently using this code on the nginx proxy:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

I've already tried with:

```
location /homeassistant {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

But this is not working at all..

I also used this guide here: https://home-assistant.io/docs/ecosystem/nginx_subdomain/

How can I configure nginx to serve like described above?

Comment: What is not work? What errors are you getting? A sub domain would `sub.example.com`. Looks like you mean a subpath or subfolder proxy

Comment: Yep, I would like to redirect to  localhost:8080 when someone enters the url https://something.com/homeassidtant.

Answer (score 2):

my config for reverse proxy nginx with subdomain with https :

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  homeassistant.domain.tld;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<local-IP>:8123;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /api/websocket {
        proxy_pass http://<local-IP>:8123/api/websocket;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    }

}
```

just remove the ssl part and replace `listen 443 ssl;`  by `listen 80;`

Answer (score 0):

You mention https://something.com/homeassistant as subdomain. To my understanding a subdomain is something like https://homeassistant.something.com where homeassistant is the subdomain for something.com. However, that seems a minor detail.

Do you use docker for your set up? I have set up homeassistant on a subdomain using a docker configuration like this:

**Nginx Proxy in a docker container**

```
docker run --name nginx-proxy \
-p 80:80 -p 443:443 -d --restart=always -v /etc/nginx/conf.d -v /etc/nginx/vhost.d -v /usr/share/nginx/html -v /etc/nginx/certs/:/etc/nginx/certs:ro --label com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy nginx
```

next, create template for config-generator:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/master/nginx.tmpl > /etc/nginx/templates/nginx.tmpl
```

**Nginx proxy config generator that set's up the proxy**

```
docker run --name nginx-config-gen \
-d --restart=always --volumes-from nginx-proxy -v /etc/nginx/templates/:/etc/docker-gen/templates/:ro  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro --label com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.docker_gen jwilder/docker-gen -notify-sighup nginx-proxy -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**SSL companion that handles your SSL certificates**

```
docker run --name nginx-letsencrypt \
-d --restart=always --volumes-from nginx-proxy -v /etc/nginx/certs/:/etc/nginx/certs:rw -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
```

So when you have this running, you have an SSL ofloading proxy that automatically configures for new images. Next we can add:

```
docker run --name domain.com \
-p 8888:80 -d --restart=always -v /etc/nginx/apps/www.domain:/etc/nginx/conf.d -e VIRTUAL_HOST=www.domain.com -e LETSENCRYPT_HOST=www.domain.com -e LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=hosting@domain.com nginx
```

to start a webserver for your domain, bind it automatically to your proxy and get a SSL certificate for it. You can add more sites in the same way, as long as the domain is unique. Using a subdomain for homeAssistant can be something like homeassistant.domain.com like this:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8123 --name home-assistant --net=host --restart=always --device=/dev/ttyACM0  -v /opt/homeAssistant:/config -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -e VIRTUAL_HOST=homeassistant.domain.com -e LETSENCRYPT_HOST=homeassistant.domain.com -e LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=hosting@domain.com   homeassistant/home-assistant
```

In that case, make sure to create an empty www directory in your home-assistant config folder (/opt/homeAssistant) in this example, in order to enable the SSL domain test to be done by letsEncrypt.